# Visual Studio 2010 Compilation Error

Tags: visual-studio

I’ve been trialing the current version of Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Beta and have come across a strange problem. When I try to compile any project, I get the error message “The operation could not be completed”, with no further information.

This happens both with C#, C++ and VB.NET projects and regardless of whether the project is an existing solution or I’m creating a new one.

Has anyone else experienced this and are there any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you changed your font settings in Visual Studio by any chance?

There seems to be some issues with fonts in VS2010 beta at the moment. I have found reverting to the default fonts may fix this issue. Potentially the windows system font could cause this issue also if it is non-standard.

Sound bizzare i know!